# How change the numeric format of axis on R chord diagram to 1k, 2k, etc?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels, chord-diagram

I'm trying to display the numeric values on the axis of an R chord diagram so that thousands are represent with a k. For example, 1000 would display as 1K, 2000 would display 2k, etc. Can anyone kindly advise how and / or if this is possible?

I've created the following function to convert numeric inputs into this 'k' format, but am unable to implement it correctly in the circos.trackPlotRegion portion of the chord diagram.

## First, I created a function to make this conversion:

```r
require(sitools)
f2si2 <- function(number,rounding=F){

  lut <- c(1e-24, 1e-21, 1e-18, 1e-15, 1e-12, 1e-09, 1e-06, 
           0.001, 1, 1000, 1e+06, 1e+09, 1e+12, 1e+15, 1e+18, 1e+21, 
           1e+24)

  pre <- c("y", "z", "a", "f", "p", "n", "u", "m", "", "k", 
           "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y")

  ix <- findInterval(number, lut)

  if (lut[ix]!=1) {
    if (rounding==T) {
      sistring <- paste(round(number/lut[ix]), pre[ix])
    } else {
      sistring <- paste(number/lut[ix], pre[ix])
    }

  }else{
    sistring <- as.character(number)
  }

  return(sistring)

}
```

## How can I use the above function (or anything else) in the circos.axis() #function so that it transforms the output to 1k, etc?

```
# Here's some very crude code as an example. I'd want the 1000 to read #1k,  
10000 to read 10k, etc. along the axis.
```

```r
library(circlize)


# create test data
mat = matrix(1:200, 10, 20)
rownames(mat) = paste0("S", 1:10)
colnames(mat) = paste0("E", 1:20)

# create chord diagram
circos.par(canvas.ylim=c(-1.5, 1.5), 
           track.margin = c(0.01, 0))

chordDiagram(mat, annotationTrack = "grid") #, grid.col = grid.col)

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  # print axis  
  circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.7, major.tick.percentage = 0.2 
              , sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 1)

  # print sector label
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + 3, sector.name, facing = "clockwise",
              niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5)) 
}, bg.border = NA)
```

[image: Diagram]